# Determining graph biconnection from degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

The title is self-explanatory: having the degree sequence of a graph, how can I find whether it is biconnected? The fact that I can't manage to draw one with such property does not mean that it does not exist...

Also, if I manage to draw a biconnected graph from the degree sequence, does this imply that *all connected graphs* with that degree sequence are biconnected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Casteels: I edited.

Comment: I've changed the wording to the more standard term degree sequence instead of score. Hope that's ok.

Comment: What about self-loops in a graph?

Comment: @Jared I'm considering graphs without self-loops.

Answer (score 6):

Two graphs with degree sequence $(2,2,2,2,2,2)$ are the (biconnected) $6$-cycle, and the (disconnected) graph consisting of two disjoint $3$-cycles. So the answer to your question is that the degree sequence can't even tell you about connectedness in general, let alone biconnectedness.

There are also degree sequences that are realizable by both biconnected graphs and connected graphs that are not biconnected. For example, for both graphs in the above example, add a single edge between two non-adjacent vertices. You get two graphs with degree sequence $(2,2,2,2,3,3)$: a $6$-cycle with a chord, and two disjoint triangles joined by a single edge. Of course one is biconnected, the other is connected but not biconnected.

However, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287063/problem-of-graph-connectivity-with-degree-sequences) for a sufficient condition on the degree sequence that will ensure $k$-connectedness.

Comment: Thanks. Given a degree sequence that describes at least a biconnected graph, are all *connected* graphs described by it biconnected?

Comment: @lodo : Sadly, no. Consider the sequence 4.3^4.2^4 and the graph of an 8-cycle with a vertex in the center connected to four others. This can be converted to a graph with a pair of squares connected at a single point and an edge across the diagonals. Bit hard to explain in text, sorry..

Comment: @gilleain Thanks.

Comment: @lodo I provided an easier counterexample and edited it into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are indeed counterexamples; graphs with the same degree sequence but different biconnectivity. As a visual summary of the examples given, see this:

[image: Isodegree pairs]

The vertices are coloured by degree. There is a simple procedure, given a graph with a particular degree sequence, to produce another graph with the same degree sequence (isodegree?). As shown in the upper example (from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1328552/26904) answer) two edges can be swapped between four vertices to make another graph.

Comment: Nice pictures. What did you use to make them?

Comment: @Casteels OmniGraffle - not the best perhaps for graph/network diagrams, and Mac-only - but quite nice for quick sketches.

Comment: @Casteels Oh, and thanks! Sorry for co-opting your example, but it was much simpler than mine :)